# Generating 3D graphic by PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, pyopengl

I'm using PyOpenGL to generate the 3D sea surface according to "2D wave equation". The main purpose is to show the dynamic graphic of "2D wave equation".But it keeps telling me this error:

```
E:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\mytest>python seawave_2d_opengl.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\
special.py", line 130, in safeCall
    return function( *args, **named )
  File "seawave_2d_opengl.py", line 106, in Draw
    glVertex3f(x,y,z)
  File "E:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\p
latform\baseplatform.py", line 402, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
GLUT Display callback <function Draw at 0x0000000004086950> with (),{} failed: r
eturning None argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

E:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\mytest>
```

Here is the code:

```
from numpy import linspace,zeros,sin,pi,exp,sqrt
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
import sys

def solver0(I, f, c, bc, Lx, Ly, nx, ny, dt, tstop, user_action=None):
    dx = Lx/float(nx)
    dy = Ly/float(ny)
    x = linspace(0, Lx, nx+1)  #grid points in x dir
    y = linspace(0, Ly, ny+1)  #grid points in y dir
    if dt <= 0:                #max time step?
        dt = (1/float(c))*(1/sqrt(1/dx**2 + 1/dy**2))
    Cx2 = (c*dt/dx)**2
    Cy2 = (c*dt/dy)**2  #help variables
    dt2 = dt**2

    up = zeros((nx+1,ny+1))  #solution array
    u = up.copy()            #solution at t-dt
    um = up.copy()           #solution at t-2*dt

    #set initial condition:
    t =0.0
    for i in range(0,nx):
        for j in range(0,ny):
            u[i,j] = I(x[i], y[j])
    for i in range(1,nx-1):
        for j in range(1,ny-1):
            um[i,j] = u[i,j] + \
                      0.5*Cx2*(u[i-1,j] - 2*u[i,j] + u[i+1,j]) + \
                      0.5*Cy2*(u[i,j-1] - 2*u[i,j] + u[i,j+1]) + \
                      dt2*f(x[i], y[j], t)
    #boundary values of um (equals t=dt when du/dt=0)
    i = 0
    for j in range(0,ny): um[i,j] = bc(x[i], y[j], t+dt)
    j = 0
    for i in range(0,nx): um[i,j] = bc(x[i], y[j], t+dt)
    i = nx
    for j in range(0,ny): um[i,j] = bc(x[i], y[j], t+dt)
    j = ny
    for i in range(0,nx): um[i,j] = bc(x[i], y[j], t+dt)

    if user_action is not None:
        user_action(u, x, y, t)   #allow user to plot etc.

    while t <= tstop:
        t_old = t
        t += dt

        #update all inner points:
        for i in range(1,nx-1):
            for j in range(1,ny-1):
                up[i,j] = -um[i,j] + 2*u[i,j] + \
                          Cx2*(u[i-1,j] - 2*u[i,j] + u[i+1,j]) + \
                          Cy2*(u[i,j-1] - 2*u[i,j] + u[i,j+1]) + \
                          dt2*f(x[i], y[j], t_old)

        #insert boundary conditions:
        i = 0
        for j in range(0,ny): up[i,j] = bc(x[i], y[j], t)
        j = 0
        for i in range(0,nx): up[i,j] = bc(x[i], y[j], t)
        i = nx
        for j in range(0,ny): up[i,j] = bc(x[i], y[j], t)
        j = ny
        for i in range(0,nx): up[i,j] = bc(x[i], y[j], t)

        if user_action is not None:
            user_action(up, x, y, t)

        um, u, up = u, up, um  #update data structures
    return u  #dt might be computed in this function
#Actually,the book wrote `return dt`,but I changed `dt` to `u`
def I(x, y):
    return exp(-(x-Lx/2.0)**2/2.0 -(y-Ly/2.0)**2/2.0)
def f(x, y, t):
    return sin(2*x*y*pi*t/Lx)  #defined by myself
def bc(x, y, t):
    return 0.0
#These three functions are some basic functions related to the first function "solver0"

Lx = 10
Ly = 10
c = 1.0
dt = 0
nx = 40
ny = 40
tstop = 20

#The following part is to generate 3D graphics,where I must make mistakes:
def init():
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)  

def Draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3f(0,0,1.0)
    glBegin(GL_LINES)   
    for t in range(0,20,1):
        z = solver0(I, f, c, bc, Lx, Ly, nx, ny, dt, t, user_action=None)
        glVertex3f(x,y,z) 
 #x and y cannot be used here because they are not defined as global variables.
    glEnd()
    glFlush  

def Update():
    global t
    t += 0.1
    glutPostRedisplay() 

def main():    
    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA)
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600)
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,50)
    glutCreateWindow("2D Wave Equations".encode("cp932"))
    init()
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw)
    glutIdleFunc(Update)
    glutMainLoop()   

main()
```

What mistake did I made? Can someone help me of this? :(

Comment: Sounds like the variable `z` is not of a proper type. Check the outout of `solver0(...)`. Maybe you missed to return the result.

Comment: @jochen I did return the result. So `z` cannot be defined like this? I thought `z` is a type `array`...

Comment: The stacktrace points to `glVertex3f(x,y,z)` and tells you that the type of one of the arguments is wrong. Just doublecheck the type of all three arguments (e.g. with `print type(x), type(y), type(z)`).

Comment: @jochen You're right.The type of `z` is wrong. It shows that the type of x and y is `numpy.float64`,and the type of z is `numpy.ndarry`. How can I solve this problem? I tried to convert the type of z by `float(z)`, but it didn't work and said `only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: Your should print the shape of z `print z.shape`. It will show that `z` has more than one element. The problem is probably, that `solver0` computes an array of `z` and NOT the `z` of the particular `x` and `y` you are going to paint. My guess is based on the fact that `x` and `y` do not appear in the call to `solver0()`.

Comment: @jochen Actually, `x` and `y` are the arguments of `I` and `f` in `solver0` so it includes the pass of the arguments. Theoretically, each `z` should be related to each `x` , `y`, `t`. I wrote like this before: ` for i in range(nx): z = solver0(I, f, c, bc, Lx, Ly, nx, ny, dt, t, user_action=None), glVertex3f(x[i],y[i],z[i])` But it didn't work. I'm out of my mind...

Comment: @jochen Well, after I print the shape of `x`,`y` and `z`, it shows that `x :41`,`y:41`,`z:41,41`..So z is a matrix...That's why I cannot use `glvertex3f`. I have to figure this out..Thank you very much for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can guess from the stacktrace, one of the arguments (the third?!?) in `glVertex3f(x,y,z)` has a wrong type. The discussion in the comments made clear that `z` is a two dimensional `ndarray` while `glVertex3f()` expects scalars. It looks like `solver0()` computes an array of `z` values instead of one z-value per call.

EDIT
I now sort of understand what `solver0()` does. The function should be documented in the book where it was printed in. Although Stackoverflow is not meant to give interpretations of copy and paste code, I'll give a little overview of what I think the function does:

1. Lx and Ly give the range of all x and y
2. nx and ny give the number of x and y value between 0 and Lx, Ly that are used.
3. The function computes an array of x and y values at wich the z-value (`up`) is computed.
4. It computes `up` for several time values from 0 to `tstop` with a step width `dt`.
5. If a user function `user_action` is given, it is called after `up` was computed. The userfunction is called with `up, x, y, t` as arguments.

To sum things up: One call of `solver0` computes all x, y, and z values for a given range of x and y value and a given time span with a given resolution.

Comment: Sorry,I don't quite understand what you mean. As you know, `z` is a two dimensional `ndarry`,how can I solve this problem by PyOpenGL? I just want use `glvertex` to plot each `x` `y` and `z` in order to generate a 3D curves graphic.Please forgive me that I know very little about this...

Comment: Don't worry about asking questions. I don't know how `solver0()` works. You have to work that out first. There should be some documentation or you should contact the developer. Just because x and y are global does not mean they are the arguments of `I` and `f`. In the line `I(4,5)` the arguments of `I` would be  `(4,5)` and not the global `(x, y)`. Working with globals is usually no good idea anyways. Additonially using `for x in x:` is a bad idea  because in that way you override your global `x` with an element of it.

Comment: Oh, I see. `x` and `y` are not passed to `I` and `f`...I have pasted the code to `solver0`. It is from a book and I modified a little.Actually,`x` and `y` are defined in `solver0` already, but I cannot use it outside this function,so I defined `x` and `y` in the main body by myself,and apparently I did a wrong thing. So what I should do now is to figure out how I can plot the curves...I'm confused again...

Comment: Whether my method to plot curves is wrong? I plotted a 2D curve before in this way. So naturally I also used this method to plot 3D curves. But It seemed to be many problems.Actually, I want the curve to move with `t` so as to show the animation. I think I must modify `Draw` function, but I don't know how...

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining these to me.So whether I can combine `solver0` with `OpenGL`. It seems that `solver0` has done everything, so I should not use a loop in OpenGL to plot the curve. I should think about that..Thank you very much for your patience and help.

Comment: I can't think of how to write `Draw` function to plot `solver0`..When I want to use `glvertex3f(x,y,z)`, I will come up with that `x` and `y` are not global variables,and `z` is a 2 dimensional array.So frustrating...